# Python: Combining a list of lists

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

Suppose I have a list of lists, like `[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]]`. What is the most elegant way in python to get `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]`?

Comment: I found this one: `import itertools` and then `myCombinedList = itertools.chain(*mylistOfLists)` Helped me get going!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
myCombinedList = []
[myCombinedList.extend(inner) for inner in mylistOfLists]
```

Or:

```
import itertools
myCombinedIterable = itertools.chain.from_iterable(mylistOfLists)
myCombinedList = list(myCombinedIterable)
```

Comment: If you want to extend the list, yes. (You can't extend something that's not already there).

Answer (score 0):

```
res=[]    
for item in mylistOfList:
        res+=item
```